# How to check the availability of Maven project dependence

Tags: maven, jenkins

I need to check the availability of Maven project dependences. If something will be missing, I want build that parts. I try use bash script with `mvn -o dependency:list`:

```
mvn -o dependency:list 
| grep ":.*:.*:.*" 
| cut -d] -f2- 
| sed 's/:[a-z]*$//g' 
| grep "xxx" 
| sort -u 
| awk -F: '$1 ~ /xxx/ {print "xxy/" $2, $4}; $1 ~ /yyy/ {print "yyx/" $2, $4}' 
| tr '\n' ' '
```

Unfortunately if dependence is missing (deleting repo from .m2/repository) this not work, and return only available repo, because command stop at first non exist dependence, and skip next module.

```
[INFO] user-panel .................................... SUCCESS [  0.613 s]
[INFO] db-commons .................................... SUCCESS [  0.165 s]
[INFO] process-scheduler ............................. FAILURE [  0.056 s]
[INFO] user-panel-main ............................... SKIPPED
```

Next I try to use `dependency:analyze`, `dependency:tree`, `dependency:resolve` but result is the same. I just need check availability of all dependency without skipping. Is there any way to archive that?  Or is simpler method? That's my full code:

```
import java.io.File 
def PATH='/app/jenkins/bin:/app/jenkins/java/bin:/app/jenkins/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin'
//I use local repo for simulate offline/ no repo 


def BuildDep(repo, version) {
    node('master'){
        def folder = new File( 'deps' )
        if( !folder.exists() ) {folder.mkdirs()}
        dir('deps'){
            deleteDir()
            rp = "git@githost:" + repo + ".git"
            println "RP = " + rp
            TAG = sh(script: " git ls-remote --tags $rp | tail -1 | awk '{ print \$2}' " , returnStdout: true)
            println "TAG = " + TAG
            checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: rp]], branches: [[name: TAG ]]], poll: false
            sh "pwd && ls -l"
            sh(script: "export PATH=${PATH} && cd . && /app/jenkins/bin/build_deploy ", returnStdout: true)
        }
    }

}

node {
  stage('SCM') {
      deleteDir()
      if ( TAG == '') {
          git '${repoName}'
      } else {
          gitRef = (GIT_SELECTOR == 'TAG' ? "refs/tags/${TAG}" : "refs/heads/${TAG}")
          checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: repoName]], branches: [[name: gitRef ]]], poll: false
      }
  }
  stage('Check dependency'){
    dependency = sh(script: '''export PATH=${PATH} && ~/bin/mvn -o dependency:list | grep ":.*:.*:.*" | cut -d] -f2- | sed 's/:[a-z]*$//g' | grep "xxx" | sort -u | awk -F: '$1 ~ /xxx/ {print "xxy/" $2, $4}; $1 ~ /yyy/ {print "yyx/" $2, $4}' | tr '\n' ' ' ''', returnStdout: true)
    if (dependency.empty) {
            println "NO  DEPENDANCY IS NEEDED"
    } else {
        len = dependency.split(' ').size()
        for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i += 2 ) {
        r = dependency.tokenize(' ')[i]
        rt = r.substring(r.indexOf("/") + 1);
        v = dependency.tokenize(' ')[i+1]
        isIn = sh(script: "find ~/.m2/repository/ -type d -name ${rt} | xargs ls | grep ${v}" ,returnStdout: true)
        if (isIn.trim() == v) {
            println r + " " +v + " - WE GOT THIS !"
        } else {
            println r + " " +v + " - MISSING - BUILD!",
            BuildDep(r, v);
        }
        }
    }
  }

  stage('Build'){
      sh """export PATH=${PATH} && 
        cd . && /app/jenkins/bin/build_withsonar """
  }

}
```

Comment: What does it mean missing dependency? So you are using a dependency and it's not available? Does that mean you don't use a repository manager ?

Comment: For example for project A, version 1.2 need three another projects with version 1.2. Missing dependency means there is only one "another projects with version 1.2", I just want to list which projects I need to build in version 1.2.

Comment: repeating the question: Do you use a repository manager which contains all released artifacts ?

Comment: No, some projects need another projects from another git repo, which i should build first.

Comment: That's the biggest problem you have...all project should be built on a CI server and deploy their artifacts to the repository manager so others can simply consume them...makes life easier....

Comment: I know that, but not everything depends of me :) All build artifacts  goes to repository manager, but at first i need to build it. I get new apps version as a spirit result it's 10, 11 different apps in one time. To build one i need build another, and it's a lot of manual work. My case is build it in one big flow, not before. So it's possibility to run  dependency plugin in that way ?

Comment: @3sky I understand your problem. In my case, due to infrastructure restriction , a repository manager was not possible. So my solution was create a job called : install-dependencies. This job has a list of dependency repositories and mvn commands to install it. I executed this job before the main project

Comment: I thought about it and this is the most reasonable way out.I will do a `while` loop, for all another build. Thanks a lot for conception.